# Optimize grouping array of hashes by date

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting, hash

Given array

```
[
  {date: '2014-01-01', a: 5, b:1},
  {date: '2014-01-01', xyz: 11},
  {date: '2014-10-10', qbz: 5},
  {date: '2014-10-10', v: 4, q: 1, strpm: -99}
]
```

I want to group by date and output an array of hashes

```
ouput = [
 {date: 2014-01-01, a: 5, b:1, xyz: 11 },
 {date: 2014-10-10, qbz: 5, v: 4, q: 1, strpm: -99},
]
```

I am solving it in Ruby and have a solution but it seems inefficient.

```
def arrayt(inputarray)
    outputarray=[];
    inputarray.each do |x|
        tindex = includes(outputarray,x[:date])
        if tindex == -1
            outputarray.push(x)
        else
            outputarray[tindex].merge!(x)
        end
    end
    return outputarray
end

def includes(array,date)
    array.each_with_index do |temp,index|
        if date==temp[:date]
            return index
        end
    end
    return -1
end
```

Any help with a more elegant solution would be appreciated

Comment: Not sure if you could do this in ruby, but if you can you could use the first element of each array element as a hash (or dictionary) key, and then append whatever is after to it to that hash slot.

Comment: Use `group_by` and then get the `.values`

Comment: Probably better suited to Code Review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[
  {date: '2014-01-01', a: 5, b:1},
  {date: '2014-01-01', xyz: 11},
  {date: '2014-10-10', qbz: 5},
  {date: '2014-10-10', v: 4, q: 1, strpm: -99}
]
.group_by(&:first).map{|_, v| v.inject(:merge)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that employs the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update({ g[:date]=>g }) { |_,ov,nv| ov.merge(nv) } }.values
```

To wit:

```
    hash = arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
      h.update({ g[:date]=>g }) { |_,ov,nv| ov.merge(nv) } }
    #=>{"2014-01-01"=>{:date=>"2014-01-01", :a=>5, :b=>1, :xyz=>11},
    #   "2014-10-10"=>{:date=>"2014-10-10", :qbz=>5, :v=>4, :q=>1, :strpm=>-99}} 
    hash.values
    #=> [{:date=>"2014-01-01", :a=>5, :b=>1, :xyz=>11},
    #    {:date=>"2014-10-10", :qbz=>5, :v=>4, :q=>1, :strpm=>-99}]
```